# Why do i keep getting the 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable' error?

Tags: python, list

I keep getting the 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable' error. All I am doing is sorting this list. Isn't this how you do it? I am copy pasting code from FreeCodeCamp and it's running for then. I am doing this on Google Colab by the way.

`my_list = ["banana", "cherry", "apple"]

new_list = sorted(my_list)

print(new_list)`

Comment: The only reason this would fail is if you somehow set `sorted` or `print` to `None`.  Your posted code doesn't do that though.

Comment: there is no any problem with your code...!